# How to SQL One to Many Relationship?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have two tables:

A

```
Aid: 1
Aid: 2
Aid: 3
```

B

```
Bid: 1 - Aid: 1 - qty: 2
Bid: 2 - Aid: 1 - qty: 2
Bid: 3 - Aid: 1 - qty: 5
Bid: 4 - Aid: 2 - qty: 3
Bid: 5 - Aid: 2 - qty: 2
Bid: 6 - Aid: 2 - qty: 2
```

How can I Sql query to get only row of table A that has Table B qty = 2?

The expected result is:

```
Aid: 1
Aid: 2
```

I've tried this:

```
Select A.Aid FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.Aid = B.Aid WHERE B.qty = 2
```

However, this gives me the result more than I need:

```
Aid: 1
Aid: 1
Aid: 2
Aid: 2
```

Yes I don't care what's the Bid is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group by `Aid`

```
Select 
 A.Aid 
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B ON A.Aid = B.Aid 
WHERE B.qty = 2
GROUP BY A.Aid
```

**Note:** `GROUP BY A.Aid` ensures there will be at most one entry for each `A.Aid`

**EDIT:**

Using `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT
 DISTINCT A.Aid 
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B ON A.Aid = B.Aid 
WHERE B.qty = 2
```

**Note:** `DISTINCT` removes the duplicate rows in the final result set.

Comment: This would be more appropriately done with `SELECT DISTINCT` which is intended to deduplicate the result set than with `GROUP BY`, intended to use with aggregates.  Same result in this case, but semantically different.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski can you help to provide the answer by using SELECT DISTINCT? that would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes `DISTINCT` fits better here @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: @Vicheanak The INNER JOIN query you attempted is nearly there, just add the keyword `SELECT DISTINCT A.Aid....` and everything else is the same.  But that only applies if you are truly only retrieving one column from `A`. If you have other columns and don't care about the result, use a correlated subquery and possibly a group aggregate

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I've tested with retrieving 2 columns from tableA. If my tableA has another column, Aname, then I can add SELECT
 DISTINCT A.Aid, A.Aname without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

In general the trick to writing SQL queries is to think of what you want to do in English, then try to rewrite it using SQL keywords.

If I rewrite your sentence "get only row of table A that has Table B qty = 2" a little more SQL-y, you can say "*select* only row of table A *where* there *exists* a row in Table B with qty = 2 for that Aid".

So, you can use an correlated subquery with `EXISTS`:

```
select *
from A
where exists (
    select 1
    from B
    where B.Aid = A.Aid
    and B.qty = 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

please try:

```
Select Distinct A.Aid FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.Aid = B.Aid WHERE B.qty = 2
```